# Why when i refresh browser it redirect me to the login in Laravel and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, refresh, laravel-sanctum

I'm having a problem with the login state of the application. The problem is when I log in and try to refresh the browser, and it redirects me to the login page. My guess here is the routing has the problem. Also, the token has not yet expired. This is what my code looks like.

**RequireAuth.jsx**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

    const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles }) => {
      const { auth } = useAuth();
      const location = useLocation();


      return (
        auth?.role_id
        ? (
        allowedRoles.some(role => role === auth.role_id)
          ? <Outlet />
          : auth.user
            ? <Navigate to="/unauthorized" state={{from: location }} replace />
            : <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />
          )
        : <Navigate to="/login" state={{from: location }} replace />
      );
    }
    export default RequireAuth;
```

**Login.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import * as MUI from '../../import';
import axios from '../../api/axios';
import BGIMG from '../../assets/SchoolBG1.jpg';
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import useLoginStore from '../Store/LoginStore'
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import { DevTool } from '@hookform/devtools';


const defaultTheme = MUI.createTheme();
const EMAIL_REGEX =  /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
const LOGIN_URL = '/api/login'

export default function Login() {
  const { setAuth } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState();

  const {
    errMsg,
    setErrMsg,
    loading,
    setLoading,
    showPassword,
    expirationTime,
    setExpirationTime,
    handleTogglePassword,
    token,
    setToken,
  } = useLoginStore();
  
  const form = useForm();
  const { register, handleSubmit, control, formState } = form;
  const { errors } = formState;
 
  //Accepted Domains for the email
  const isSupportedDomain = (email) => {
    const supportedDomains = ['yahoo.com', 'gmail.com', 'outlook.com'];
    const educationalDomainRegex = /@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.(edu(\.[a-zA-Z]{2})?|[a-zA-Z]{2}\.[a-zA-Z]{2})$/;
    const domain = email.split('@')[1];
    return supportedDomains.includes(domain) || educationalDomainRegex.test(email);
  };

  const csrf = () => axios.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie")

  const onSubmit = async (data, event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
    setLoading(true);
    await csrf()
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        }
      };
      const postData = {
        email_address: data.email_address,
        password: data.password,
      };

      const response = await axios.post(
        LOGIN_URL,
        JSON.stringify(postData),
        config,
      ); 

      const { remember_token, user, roles_name, expires_at } = response.data;

      setLoggedIn(remember_token)

      console.log(JSON.stringify(response?.data));
      
      const role_id = response?.data?.user?.role_id;

      setExpirationTime(new Date(expires_at).getTime());
      
      setLoading(false);

      // Set the authenticated user state using setAuth from your useAuth hook
      setAuth({ user, remember_token, roles_name, role_id, expirationTime});

        // Set the token and expiration time in local storage
        localStorage.setItem('remember_token', remember_token);

      const rolePath = role_id === 1  ? '/'  : role_id === 2 ? '/' : role_id === 3 ? '/scholar-dashboard' : '/login';
  
      // Navigate the user to the intended route (from variable contains the intended route)
      navigate(rolePath);
      
    } catch (err) {
      setLoading(false);
      if(err.response?.status === 422){
        setErrMsg('Email address and password are required');
      }
      else if(err.response?.status === 409){
        setErrMsg('Email Address already been taken');
      }
      else if(err.response?.status === 500){
        setErrMsg('Server Error');
      }
      else if (err.response?.status === 401) {
        setErrMsg('Login failed. Please check your credentials and try again.');
      }
      else{
        setErrMsg('Network error occurred. Please try again.');
      }
    }
  }


  {/* When its size to a Tablet mode the Left Grid display none  */}
  const isMobile = MUI.useMediaQuery('(max-width:768px)');

  return (
    <MUI.ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>

    {/*  Right Grid is the Picture Grid  */}
    <MUI.Grid container component="main" sx={{ height: '100vh' }}>
      <MUI.CssBaseline />
      {!isMobile && (
        <MUI.Grid
          container 
          alignItems='center' 
          justifyContent='center'
          item
          xs={false}
          sm={12}
          md={7}
          sx={{
              display: 'flex', // Use flex container
              flexDirection: 'column', // Stack items vertically
              alignItems: 'center', // Center items horizontally
              justifyContent: 'center', // Center items vertically
              backgroundImage: `url(${BGIMG})`,
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundColor: (t) =>
                t.palette.mode === 'light' ? t.palette.grey[50] : t.palette.grey[900],
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              backgroundPosition: 'center',
              textAlign: 'center',
              padding: '2rem', // Add padding to the content
            }}
        >
          <br />
          <MUI.Typography variant="h2" color="background.paper" paragraph>
            Welcome to Gado and Jess <br/> Jalandoni Scholarship Program
          </MUI.Typography>
          <MUI.Typography variant="h5" color="background.paper" paragraph>
            Empowering dreams through education.
          </MUI.Typography>
        </MUI.Grid>
      )}

      {/* Left Grid is the Login Form  */}
      <MUI.Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={5} component={MUI.Paper} elevation={6} square container 
        alignItems='center' 
        justifyContent='center'
        sx={{
          p: 3,
        }}>

        {loading && (
            <MUI.Backdrop
            open={loading}
            sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
            >
              <MUI.Box
                sx={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: '50%',
                  left: '50%',
                  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
                  zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 2,
                }}
              >
                <MUI.CircularProgress />
              </MUI.Box>
            </MUI.Backdrop>
          )}
        
        {errMsg && (
        <p id="errMsg" style={{ color: 'red' }}>
          {' '}
          <MUI.InfoIcon className="infoErr" /> {errMsg}
        </p>
      )}

        <MUI.Box
          sx={{
            my: 1,
            mx: 4,
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            width: '100%', 
          }}>
            <img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TianMeds/image--stocks-for-coding/main/Scholarlink%20Logos.png' alt="Logo" style={{ width: '200px', height: '150px' }} />
            <MUI.Typography component="h3" variant="h4" sx={{ textAlign: 'left', fontWeight: 'bold'  }}>
              Login
            </MUI.Typography>

            <MUI.Typography>
              Welcome back! Please enter your details.
            </MUI.Typography>
          <br/>
          {/* Email Textfield  */} 
              <MUI.Box component="form" sx={{ mt: 1,  width: '100%', }}  onSubmit={(event) => handleSubmit((data) => onSubmit(data, event))(event)} method='post' >
                <MUI.Grid item>
                  <MUI.TextField
                    variant='standard'
                    margin="dense"
                    fullWidth
                    type='email'
                    id="email_address"
                    autoComplete='off'
                    placeholder='Email Address'
                    {...register('email_address', { 
                      pattern: {
                        value: EMAIL_REGEX,
                        message: 'Invalid email address'
                      },
                      validate: 
                        value => isSupportedDomain(value) || 'Email domain not supported',
                      required: {
                        value: true,
                        message: 'Email address is required'
                      },
                    })}
                  />
                  {errors.email_address &&(
                    <p id="errMsg">
                      <MUI.InfoIcon className="infoErr" /> 
                      {errors.email_address.message}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </MUI.Grid>
                <br/> <br/>
                {/* Password Textfield  */}
                <MUI.Grid item>
                  <MUI.TextField
                    variant='standard'
                    margin="dense"
                    fullWidth
                    type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                    id="password"
                    placeholder='Password'
                    InputProps={{
                      endAdornment: (
                        <MUI.InputAdornment position="end">
                          <MUI.IconButton onClick={handleTogglePassword} edge="end">
                            {showPassword ? 
                            <MUI.VisibilityIcon sx={{ fontSize: '1.2rem' }} /> : <MUI.VisibilityOffIcon sx={{ fontSize: '1.2rem' }}  />
                            }
                          </MUI.IconButton>
                        </MUI.InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }} 
                    {...register('password', { 
                      required: {
                        value: true,
                        message: 'Password is required'
                      },
                    })}
                  />
                  {errors.password &&(
                    <p id="errMsg">
                      <MUI.InfoIcon className="infoErr" /> 
                      {errors.password.message}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </MUI.Grid>

            <br/>

              {/* Remember Me Checkbox  */}
              <MUI.FormControlLabel
                control={<MUI.Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                label="Remember me"
              />

              {/* Login Button  */}
              <MUI.Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2, color: 'white', backgroundColor: '#311b92', borderRadius: '10px' }}
              >
                Sign In
              </MUI.Button>

            {/* Forgot Password Link  */}
              <MUI.Grid container>
                <MUI.Grid item xs>
                  <MUI.Link href="#" variant="body2" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                    Forgot password?
                  </MUI.Link>
                </MUI.Grid>
              </MUI.Grid>

              
          </MUI.Box>
        </MUI.Box>
      </MUI.Grid>
      <DevTool control={control} />
    </MUI.Grid>
  </MUI.ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

**API.php**

```
//Protected Route
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
    Route::post('/scholars', [ScholarController::class, 'store']);
    Route::put('/scholars/{user_id}', [ScholarController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/scholars/{user_id}', [ScholarController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store']);
    Route::put('/users/{id}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/users/{firstname}', [UserController::class, 'destroy']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::apiResource('/scholars', ScholarController::class)->only(['index', 'show']);
    Route::apiResource('/users', UserController::class)->only(['index', 'show']);
    Route::apiResource('/roles', RoleController::class)->only(['index', 'show']);
    Route::get('/scholars/search/{user_id}', [ScholarController::class, 'search']);
    Route::get('/users/search/{firstname}', [UserController::class, 'search']);
   // Route::get('/refresh-token', [AuthController::class,'refreshToken']); 
});


**Public Route**
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/scholar', function (Request $request){
    return $request->scholar();;
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request){
    return $request->scholar();;
});
```

If there is still part of the code to be checked I'm willing to send it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the authentication state is not being persisted correctly.
let's check some steps you can take to address this issue::

Persist Authentication State:
Ensure that you are persisting the authentication state correctly, especially the token and other necessary authentication details, so that they are not lost upon a page refresh.

In your login component, after successfully logging in the user, set the token in localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('remember_token', remember_token);
```

And when the application loads, check for the token in localStorage and set the authentication state accordingly.

Check for Token on Page Load:
check for the token in localStorage and set the authentication state accordingly. This logic should execute once when the app initializes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('remember_token');
  if (token) {
    // Set the authentication state here
    // Example: setAuth({ token, ...otherDetails });
  }
}, []);
```